# C#: Multiprocessing like Python

Tags: c#, python, multiprocessing

Does C# provide the possibility to do multiprocessing based on data and result queues similar to Python as described [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html) for example?

Ideally the background process should be blocked until there is something in the queue to process.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean [async await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)?

Comment: I would like to have a data queue and a result queue which I hand to a background process. This process reads the data queue and writes the result into the result queue. You can refer to the link in the question for a detailed explanation how this works in Python. A feature is hereby that the background process can be blocked when the data queue is empty. In this case the process waits until there is data in the queue and then continues.

Comment: And what about [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: You can download the PDF Patterns of Parallel Programming (.NET 4.0, C#) [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222). It contains a chapter about the producer/consumer pattern. There a samples how to use the BlockingCollection.